# How to iterate through a pandas dataframe and find all rows with given value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

If I have a excel file containing hundreds of rows with information like

```
| 0 |  1  |     2      |   3   |   4   |   5  |
-----------------------------------------------
| A | 212 | 10.10.1000 | 10:10 | 10.10 | 1.10 |
-----------------------------------------------
| B | 314 | 20.20.2000 | 20:20 | 20.20 | 2.20 |
-----------------------------------------------
| B | 314 | 20.20.2000 | 20:20 | 20.20 | 2.20 |
```

And I want to iterate through them and save every row containing a certain number in the second column, how can I do that?
I tried this, but it didnt work:

```py
import pandas as pd

exsl = "excel file"
df = pd.read_excel(exsl)

value = 212

listOfMatches = []

for row in df:
  if value in row:
    listOfMatches.append(row)
```

The desired output is a list containing all rows like:

```
[[A, 212, 10.10.1000, 10:10, 10.10, 1.10],[...]]
```

Comment: No need to loop, You can use df.query("col_name == @value")

Comment: You can try `df[df[1] == 112].to_numpy().tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

On example data:

```
df= util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()


    A   B   C   D
0   0.0     0.0     foo1    2009-01-01
1   1.0     1.0     foo2    2009-01-02
2   2.0     0.0     foo3    2009-01-05
3   3.0     1.0     foo4    2009-01-06
4   4.0     0.0     foo5    2009-01-07
```

Filtering

```
df.query("B == 1")

    A   B   C   D
1   1.0     1.0     foo2    2009-01-02
3   3.0     1.0     foo4    2009-01-06
```

Returning a list of rows

```
df.query("B == 1").values.tolist()

[[1.0, 1.0, 'foo2', Timestamp('2009-01-02 00:00:00')],
 [3.0, 1.0, 'foo4', Timestamp('2009-01-06 00:00:00')]]
```